# C++ Which Exception should I use? / Determine user's input

Tags: c++, exception

I am new to C++ and am testing 'try'.
I am unsure however, what exception should be caught, when the throw may result in the division of a word or phrase by itself:

For example:

```
int current_year = 1;

//code....

cout << "What year is it?\n";
cin >> current_year;

while (n>1) {

    try{
        throw (current_year / current_year);
    }
    catch (exception) {
        cout << "What year is it?\n";
        cin >> current_year;
    }
    catch (...){
        n = 0;
```

Here, as current_year is defined as an int, but is set through a "cin <<" if the user enters a word or phrase, the program should result in an error when dividing a word by another word (hense: throw (current_year / current_year);)

but the program does not catch an error with the exception: catch (exception).
Please could someone explain what exception I should use, or how to rework this program to check whether current_year is actually a integer.

Thanks.

(One other thing: isdigit isn't working for me. I believe this is because it only recognises numbers from -1 to 255. and I am entering 2014. So if I have been using isdigit incorrectly, then please make me aware of this.)

Comment: `try` is not a function... Also, an `int` is not of type `std::exception`. Last point, never catch any broader than you absolutely know you have to.

Comment: What does "dividing a word by another word" mean? Give an example of user input which is OK, and input which you think should raise an exception.

Comment: This kind of invalid input is expected, so I wouldn't even bother throwing an exception. Tell the user what he must input, and ask for the input again.

Comment: You should test whether user inputs a number rather than always throw. You should catch an exception by reference, not by value. You don't use `isdigit` in your code at all, how could we tell if you're using it incorrectly?

Comment: See here for a working example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa0454252f00351c Also, see here for an overview of `std::exception`-derived classes: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception (You really only want to throw classes derived from `std::exception`)...

Comment: thanks, attempting now.

Comment: `isdigit` is used to check whether an individual *character* is a digit. It's not meant to be used to check whether a *string* is a *numeral*. Another thing I don't understand is why you're *always* throwing an exception. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @EattomuchBread - A user inputing data via keyboard has a high probability of the user making a mistake typing, therefore that is not an *exceptional* condition.  Throwing exceptions because the user has fat fingers isn't (or shouldn't) be a reason to use exceptions for this case.  Just use a return code or similar construct and ask the user to enter the correct input.

Answer (score 4):

You're throwing a value of type `int`, whether or not a valid value was entered. You might get some kind of error - undefined behaviour, and probably not a catchable exception - if `current_year` is zero; otherwise, you'll always throw an `int` value of 1. This could be handled by a `catch(int)` block; but that wouldn't make any sense.

If you want to throw if the user enters something other than a number, then you'll want to check the result of the input:

```
if (!(cin >> current_year)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid year");
}
```

`runtime_error` is a subclass of `exception`, so will be caught by a handler for `exception`.

Alternatively, you could define your own exception class and throw that. It's best if that is also a subclass of `exception`, so that a handler for that can at least extract an error message for it if there isn't a more specific handler. This might look something like

```
struct InvalidYear : std::runtime_error {
    InvalidYear() : std::runtime_error("Invalid year") {}
};

if (!(cin >> current_year)) {
    throw InvalidYear();
}
```

This can be caught by a specific handler for `InvalidYear`, or more generic handlers for `runtime_error` and `exception`.

Answer (score 2):

You throw an exception by type. Although the language allows any type, you should in general only throw something derived from [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception).

You have several to choose from and `std::invalid_argument` possibly makes most sense here as they've entered invalid data.

Your code makes no real sense though, you should throw if an unexpected error occurred. You should create the exception based on the text of what the user did wrong.

You just throw the number 1 (`current_year / current_year` will always be 1, unless current_year was entered as 0 in which case you have even more problems) and you would have to catch an int in your exception handler, and what would catching 1 mean anyway?

Ideally avoid `catch(...)`. It is sometimes used when you really must not allow your function to throw, e.g. you are in some worker thread and nothing will catch it and it will just cause your application to terminate when it is better to let the thread die as a failed job.